# How to check whether there are 2 similar columns in a 2-D array in C

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

Write a function that gets a 2-d array, its number of rows, its number of columns and checks whether there are 2 similar columns or not. If there are 2 similar columns, it returns true.

```
int compareArray(int a[],int b[],int size)  {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        if(a[i]!=b[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int solution(int row, int column, const int array1[row][column]) {
  int array2[3];
  int x=0;
  int tru[row];
  int temparray[row];

  while(x<column){
    for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
      array2[i] = array1[i][x];
    }   
    for (int i=0;i<column;i++){
      for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
        temparray[i] = array1[i][x];
      }    
      int sol = compareArray(array2,temparray,row);
      if (x != i){
        if (sol==0){
          return 1;     
        }
        return 0;
      } //end of if
    }
    x++;
  }  //end of while
} //End of function
```

My code returns all answers as true. How can I correct this code to return only columns that are actually similar??

Comment: What are `similar columns`? Equal? Or "almost" equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these lines:

```
for (int i=0;i<column;i++){
  for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
    temparray[i] = array1[i][x];}
```

When you are adding to `temparray` you are using `x`, which is the original column you are trying to compare against. This will make every column match because you are comparing each column only with itself.

You really want to use the `i` from the first loop here, but you can't because you have hidden it with the `i` from the second loop.

Changing your variable names would allow you to use the variable from the first loop and make the code a bit easier to read. I prefer to use longer and more meaningful variable names for anything that isn't in a single line loop:

```
for (int checkCol=0;checkCol<column;checkCol++){
  for (int r=0;r<row;r++){
    temparray[r] = array1[r][checkCol];}
```

Note: you will need to change `i` further down the code to `checkCol` (or whatever you decide to call the variable)